# while calling AWT using JNI using eclipse on MAC osx, the API hangs?

Tags: macos, java-native-interface

I am using eclipse ide for c++ compiler, I have a sample code for loading a window using Frame (AWT class) on MAC OSX, when I am loading this jar using JNI(calling java from C++), it hangs as soon as it is trying to create Frame instance. Any idea about this, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWT has its own set of threads, that are independent from the main thread.  As a result, deadlocks are common when using AWT directly.  I would suspect your issue is due to deadlock, rather than anything specific to being called via JNI.  If you don't understand what I mean, search on "AWT deadlock" and check if your code has any of the common patterns that lead to AWT deadlock.